# Scrub form submission data of "bad" characters in pre-submit javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, utf-8, character-encoding

**UPDATE:** Edited because I didn't quite know what I was talking about before.

I've got a form which is submitting to a server-side script, which uses that data to produce XML output for a web service.  The XML croaks if there are invalid characters (which I assume just means "not allowed in XML", but may have something to do with encoding) in the data.  The error occurs frequently because many users cut/paste word documents etc. to fill in the form.

I can't modify the server-side scripts that consume the data or put it into XML  (I have no access to the server), so I can't sanitize the data server-side.  In order to at least mitigate the problem until we can add some server-side sanitization, I'd like to intercept the form submission with javascript and scrub every text input and textarea of "bad" characters.

I know how to loop through the form, and am expecting I'll want to throw a regex into thisString.replace() to handle it.

What I don't know is (a) whether using .replace() with a regex is the right way to go, and if so, (b) what should actually go in the regex.  I want to allow as many characters as possible without breaking the XML output.

Thanks.

Comment: Whatever you do, you need to alert whoever in charge of the server side to do the sanitation. JS can only clean up data from normal user of the system. Malicious user can bypass the JS easily by using simple tcp connection to your http server.

Comment: Pardon? UTF-8 can encode the complete 100,000 item Unicode catalogue. What kind of characters are your users submitting?

Answer (score 2):

Generally browsers submit data as UTF-8, no matter where it was copypasted from as long as you had set the encoding to utf-8 with the http header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

There are some exceptions in IE of course.

Also, there is no such thing as non-UTF8-character. You mean that the browser encodes the form in some utf-8 incompatible encoding, such as Windows-1252.

There is nothing you can do in javascript except restrict the characters to ASCII ones but that doesn't really prevent anything but normal users. You must always check encoding on server side anyway in the case of encoding attacks.

Comment: Thanks... now I better understand what I was actually trying to ask; question updated.